# Marking points on image using getpts and zooming in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, matlab-guide, image-segmentation, zooming

I am trying to mark points using the `getpts` MATLAB function but the size of the image is large and hence the image appears in a small window, making the exact points of interest appear as tiny dots, which are difficult to identify and recognize. Until now I have been marking in the first iteration as randomly and then later zooming and finding a better position for the points. Is there any other way where the image appears enlarged sufficiently and I can mark the points in one go?

```
imshow(input_image);
[Xcoordinates, Ycoordinates] = getpts
coordinates =[Xcoordinates, Ycoordinates];
[r,c]= size(coordinates); % coordinates obtained to be written in a file
for i=1:r
    fprintf(co_ordi,'%d %d ', coordinates(i,1),coordinates(i,2));
end
fprintf(co_ordi,'\r\n'); % to introduce a new line
fclose(co_ordi);
```

Comment: Please add some code so we can efficiently help you

Comment: imshow(input_image);

[Xcoordinates, Ycoordinates] = getpts
coordinates =[Xcoordinates, Ycoordinates];

[r,c]= size(coordinates);

% coordinates obtained to be written in a file

    for i=1:r
    
         fprintf(co_ordi,'%d  %d ', coordinates(i,1),coordinates(i,2));
    
    end
fprintf(co_ordi,'\r\n');% to introduce a new line
fclose(co_ordi);

Comment: I've edited your question to include the code. Please accept the edit, and take a look at how it's done for your future questions

Comment: That was a very good help I received from you. Thank u!

Comment: Its quite unclear what you are asking. The code posted has no relation to the text you posted and the text doesnt specify a clear problem and a clear desired solution. I can only guess: You want imshow to show a bigger image? have you tried maximizing the window?

Answer (score 0):

For training an algorithm, I wanted to mark points on an image which are not visible clearly on the 'getpts' prompted window, as the size of the image is too large.

Now what I have done is to mark the points coarsely, almost nearby to its ideal position and then increasing the correctness by moving the points closer to the ideal location in second run. in the second go, i have taken a small area around the coarsely marked point, enlarged it and called 'getpts' again. That solved my problem.